# Ramda map and filter in one loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

```
const R = require('rambda')

export const test = () => {

  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  const filter = no => no > 5
  const map = no => no * 100

  // looping 2 times
  return data
    .filter(filter)
    .map(map)

  // wird 1 loop
  return data.reduce((data, no) => {
    if (!filter(no)) return data
    data.push(map(no))
    return data
  }, [])

  // I want to do something like this.
  return data.map(R.pipe(map, filter))

}
```

Hello, is it possible to map and filter in one loop using ramda or rambda?

My example:

```
return data.map(R.pipe(map, filter))
```

is returning

```
Array [
  600,
  700,
  800,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
]
```

and I need it to be `[600, 700, 800]`

Comment: What about `data.reduce( (acc, c) => (filter(c) && acc.push(map(c)), acc) ,[])`

Comment: If you are not looking for a vanilla JS answer, kindly remove **javascript** tag from the question.

Comment: I can't without changing the question :(

Comment: My answer below offers one option.  But gurvinder372's comment gives you a simple solution.  The reason your original is not working is the outer call to `map`, which transforms all elements of the list.  Starting with `filter` doesn't help, as it returns only the matching ones, but doesn't do a transform.  You really need to use `reduce` somehow or another.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with Ramda's [transducers](http://simplectic.com/blog/2015/ramda-transducers-logs/).

(Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author)

While a normal composition of regular Ramda functions will loop for every list transformation, a transduced one will run each function in the composition on each iteration.  Note that for technical reasons, the composition runs in the reverse order when using transducers.

Not every function is a transducer.  The documentation uses this note to indicate one: "Acts as a transducer if a transformer is given in list position."  This is included in both [`map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) and [`filter`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter).  There are several functions that make it easier to work with transducers.  [`into`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#into) is one of them.

Still, it might be easier to write your own `filterMap` function.  Is isn't hard:

```
const filterMap = curry((f, m, data) => reduce(
  (a, i) => f(i) ? append(m(i), a) : a, 
[], data))
```

```js
const {compose, map, filter, into, curry, reduce, append} = R;

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
const gt5 = no => {console.log(`filter: ${no}`); return no > 5;}
const times100 = no => {console.log(`map ${no}`); return no * 100;}

console.log('========= Plain composition =========')
const transform1 = compose(map(times100), filter(gt5))
console.log(transform1(data))

console.log('========== With transducers =========')
const transform2 = into([], compose(filter(gt5), map(times100)));
console.log(transform2(data))

console.log('=========== With filterMap ==========')
const filterMap = curry((f, m, data) => reduce((a, i) => f(i) ? append(m(i), a) : a, [], data))
console.log(filterMap(gt5, times100)(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

If you want to see how the transducers shine, add a `take(2)` to the end of the composition.

These add a great deal of complexity to Ramda's implementations, and there has been some talk of removing them, or trying to find a way to make them optional.  But not much has been done toward this.

Comment: Thank you!.
I will use the filterMap method.

Comment: I'm glad it helps.  But have you done the analysis to know that there is an actual performance problem with the `filter, then map` technique?  Premature optimization, and all that!

Comment: I have not done any analysis. I was just a little worried about looping multiple times over the same array, because I have a lot of filter->map->reduce cases in my codebase.

Comment: My suggestion is that you keep with the simplest code that will work until you find that optimization is actually necessary.  Often such multiple loops perform just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be.

```
const expr = R.compose(
    R.map(x => x * 100),
    R.filter(x => x > 5)
);
const result = expr([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
console.log(result);
```

updated: a one-loop way:

```
const iter = (acc, x) => (x > 5 && acc.push(x * 100), acc)
const result = R.reduce(iter, [], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Both one-loop or two-loop, execute the same logic, should no difference.

Comment: Will this solution not loop 2 times?

Comment: works the same as 
    return data
        .filter(filter)
        .map(map)

Comment: Yea I know, I am looking for a solution doing it in one loop.